# error: failed to encode '---------_dict.sql' from UTF-8 to Windows-1250

Tags: sql, git

when I download the repository I get this error from the git

> - error: failed to encode '---------_dict.sql' from UTF-8 to Windows-1250.

Then while I want to commit and push I get the same error with the same files with the **.sql** extension. Anyone have any idea? Someone had a similar problem? Could it be related to the **.gitattributes** file which has

```
* .sql text working-tree-encoding = Windows-1250
```

Comment: Please copy and paste the contents of the file.  The contents you have posted are not syntactically valid for a `.gitattibutes` file.

Answer (score 0):

This error message means that some part of the conversion failed, most likely because the contents of the file cannot be converted to windows-1250.  It's likely that the file contains UTF-8 sequences corresponding to Unicode characters that have no representation in windows-1250.

You should contact the author of the repository and notify them of this problem and ask them to fix it.  In your local system, you can add `.git/info/attributes` which has the following to force the files to UTF-8 instead:

```
*.sql text working-tree-encoding=UTF-8
```

Note that if you do this, you *must* ensure that the files you check in are actually UTF-8 and not windows-1250.